# Delete common part of dataframes in conditions. pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `male and female

```
male = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[777, 'male', 9]
                                ,[999, 'male', 9],[999, 'male', 9]])
                   ,columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

female=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[119, 'female', 9],[777, 'female', 9]
                                ,[777, 'female', 9],[999, 'female', 9]])
                   ,columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


male:
     a     b  c
0  777  male  9
1  999  male  9
2  999  male  9

female:
     a       b  c
0  119  female  9
1  777  female  9
2  777  female  9
3  999  female  9
```

I need to delete common part from both of them , but with the same amount of rows taking into account only columns `a and c`, for example if ONE row  have same value (a and c) as in second dataframe, remove both (2 rows, even when more rows match)

I have tried to use

```
df=pd.concat([male,female]).drop_duplicates(subset=['a','c'])
print(df)
     a       b  c
0  777    male  9
1  999    male  9
0  119  female  9

my expected output is:
     a       b  c
2  999    male  9
0  119  female  9
2  777  female  9
```

as result i need to delete rows which exist in second dataframe only once, drop_duplicates() is taking everything which exist more than once.
I care only to drop duplicates between dataframes

Comment: not getting the logic that you are using to remove the rows. Why is `999    male  9` in the output when it is in both df's?

Comment: Its only one time in second df , 2-1=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you.

```
df=pd.concat([male,female])
df['g'] = df.groupby(['a','b','c'])['b'].cumcount()
df1=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['a','c','g']).drop_duplicates(subset=['a','c'],keep='last').drop('g', axis=1)
print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
      a        b    c
2   999     male    9
0   119     female  9
2   777     female  9
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to separately deleted rows in both dataframes, here is my little bit different approach:

```
male['n'] = male.groupby(['a','b','c']).cumcount()
female['n'] = female.groupby(['a','b','c']).cumcount()

male = male.set_index(['a','c','n'])
female = female.set_index(['a','c','n'])

row_del = set(list(male.index)).intersection(set(list(female.index)))  # evaluate estimate pairs {("a","c",order_number)}

#
# row_del gives you intersection of indexes like this: {('999', '9', 0), ('777', '9', 0)}
#

male.drop(row_del)
female.drop(row_del)
```